# What's the behavior of using std::atomic<T> in this scenario?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, c++11

Use a global `std::atomic<int>` variable as a flag.

Main function thread : Init the flag with 1

Worker thread: Judge the atomic flag and do some work in an infinite loop

Main function sets the flag to `0` and calls `exit()` after some sleep. All the threads will be terminated.

After calling exit, It can't be guranteed whether std::atomic lasts longer than the thread life time.

Assuming `std::atomic` is in desctruction before thread termination, thread is still accessing it. What's the behavior? From the test it is OK, but I am not quite sure about it. Is there any standard reference?

Comment: Did you `detach` the worker thread?

Comment: [Documentation of exit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) explains what should happen.

Comment: “Use a global … variable …” ← This idea is always wrong, in one way or another. Also, “…after some sleep…” is a wrong idea; there’s never a reason for sleeping (without waiting for anything else) in userspace. (Alright, a multi-threading “torture test” might be an exception.) Why not properly `join()` the threads to make sure they terminate?

Comment: This the case that I can't do normal orderly shutdown. I know it's not a good usage,but in real situcation , I can't do that.

Comment: The OS thread or detached `std::(j)thread` thread - will be terminated by the OS after the C++ clean-up.  Therefore you have UB if the still running thread tries to access almost anything after `main` has exited and [`std::exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) has been implicitly called.

Comment: Side note:  If you can guarantee that your thread will never exit until after the atomic-variable has been set, one way around this problem would be to locate the atomic-variable in memory that is owned by the thread itself (e.g. on the thread's stack, or perhaps in a heap allocation owned by the thread).  Then the thread can guarantee that the atomic-variable will remain valid, simply by not deallocating that memory until after it has already been signalled to go away.  (properly join()-ing the thread would still be preferable though)

Comment: how do you  'set' the atomic? how do you 'check' the atomic? Using atomic is really hard, maybe using some mutexes and/or condvar would be less tricky to use in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Clean program termination is a hard problem.

If there is an active thread when `main` returns (or falls off the end) or `exit` is called, it is very hard to avoid undefined behavior.

Accessing any variable after the object it refers to has been destroyed in UB in C++, even if that destruction is trivial.  You can sometimes access the *storage* that a variable used after its destruction, but that is a very different thing and even looks very different (with the possible exception of some relatively new C++20 features involving primitive types, but that case doesn't include `atomic`s, so doesn't apply here).

The right way to handle this kind of problem is to keep the amount of work you do in a worker thread bounded between checks for program termination.  This in turn requires significant amounts of programmer overhead.

Sleep is usually a sign your design has serious issues.  Your code should almost always be either waiting on a signal or making forward progress on its task.

If you cannot clean up your environment, `std::abort` might be a more appropriate shutdown mechanism, as you are not cleaning up properly.  Pretending you are with `std::exit` isn't going to make things better.  But you should first attempt to do a correct shutdown.

A correct shutdown attempt could involve a semaphore counting how many threads have property shutdown, some make ready at thread exit futures to avoid race conditions, and some calls to `wait_for` to ensure you don't hang on something going wrong.  After you give everything enough time to settle and things haven't cleaned up, you surrender and `abort`, possibly logging an abnormal shutdown message as well.

This avoids the chance of your process hanging around indefinitely due to a run-away thread, but the attempt at correct shutdown means that when things don't go wrong you shut down properly and know it happened.

A call to `exit` where you are just "hoping" every thread is already done is the opposite of this.  Here, you could be doing an abnormal program shutdown *and don't know it*.  This means you don't know how often you are risking UB, can't log how often your program shuts down abnormally, and don't even know if it is **possible** for your program to shut down in an orderly way.  Instead, you are "shrugging" and hoping it isn't a problem.